# I'm getting a *variable syntax error when upgrading code to tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some tensorflow code that runs on an old tensorflow version created by the devs themselves. When trying to upgrade this code, I found the official tensorflow upgrade tool and tried to use it but I'm getting a syntax error when the tool tries to handle the `self.inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, *state_size], name="inputs")`

My code:

```
class DQNetwork:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate, name='DQNetwork'):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            # We create the placeholders
            # *state_size means that we take each elements of state_size in tuple hence is like if we wrote
            # [None, 84, 84, 4]
            self.inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, *state_size], name="inputs")
            self.actions_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name="actions_")
            
            # Remember that target_Q is the R(s,a) + ymax Qhat(s', a')
            self.target_Q = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="target")
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.placeholder` isn't in TF2. Try using the version compatible `tf.placeholder` object form TF2:

```
tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, *state_size], name="inputs")
```

There is a great [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) from the docs about this.

Comment: The problem is with `*state_size`

Comment: What about it??

Comment: Google Colab shows that the error is in that part for some reason. https://i.imgur.com/zv61C69.png